# How to print top level fields and inner array fields together using jq?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq

I have a JSON that is the output from AWS CLI.

Sample:

```
{
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "abc",
          "Key": "Name"
        },
        {
          "Value": "123",
          "Key": "App"
        }
      ],
      "Encrypted": false,
      "VolumeType": "gp2",
      "VolumeId": "vol-123",
      "State": "in-use",
      "Iops": 100,
      "SnapshotId": "snap-123",
      "CreateTime": "2019-08-27T00:51:00.971Z",
      "Size": 20
    },
    {
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "def",
          "Key": "Name"
        },
        {
          "Value": "456",
          "Key": "App"
        }
      ],
      "Encrypted": false,
      "VolumeType": "gp2",
      "VolumeId": "vol-456",
      "State": "in-use",
      "Iops": 100,
      "SnapshotId": "snap-456",
      "CreateTime": "2019-08-27T00:51:00.971Z",
      "Size": 22
    },
{
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "789",
          "Key": "App"
        }
      ],
      "Encrypted": false,
      "VolumeType": "gp2",
      "VolumeId": "vol-789",
      "State": "in-use",
      "Iops": 100,
      "SnapshotId": "snap-789",
      "CreateTime": "2019-08-27T00:51:00.971Z",
      "Size": 23
    }
]
}
```

The output will have hundreds of such volumes in array. I want to print an output that has the fields
VolumeId,Size,Name

only when Name tag exists

So far I could do something like:

```
jq .Volumes | jq '.[] | select(any(.Tags[]; .Key == "Name"))' | jq -r '[.VolumeId,.Size,.Tags[].Key]|join(",")'
```

This gives output as:

```
vol-123,20,Name,App
vol-456,22,Name,App
```

How can the jq query be changed to get something like

```
vol-123,20,abc
vol-456,22,def
```

Is it possible?

NOTE: The reason I was trying this was because I had to do multiple reports/validations on my list of volumes from AWS and did not want to run multiple AWS commands when the result is not going to change. Basing the reports on a single command also avoids any discrepancies that might occur if some volumes get added/deleted in background while you are running the multiple commands for example

Comment: Please share the AWS CLI command as well

Comment: @Amit John has mentioned it below in his answer if you have not already seen it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still looking for a `jq` solution, you can do below. Just place the required fields in an array and call the `join()` function

```
jq -r '.Volumes | map( .VolumeId, .Size, (.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name").Value)  ) | join(",")'
```

For your updated requirement of having to deal with multiple objects inside `.Volumes`, see below. By removing the `map(..)` functionality, we ensure the fields are collected in separate arrays.

The below logic, creates multiple arrays, each for one set of query fields we are doing. You can either use the `@csv` or the `join(",")` function as before.

```
jq -r '.Volumes[] | [.VolumeId, .Size, (.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name").Value)] | join(",")'
```

Comment: oh sorry.. updating the question now

Comment: Ya I used the filter you mentioned in your original answer and fused it with my half baked one and it worked like a charm. Thanks! The csv option you mentioned in your edit also works however. it results in the answer having quotations around the fields like - "vol-456",22,"def"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using the AWS CLI to describe volumes, you can use the `--query` parameter instead of `jq`:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[].[VolumeId,Size,Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value | [0]]" --output text
```

For information about the syntax, see: [JMESPath Examples — JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/examples.html)

(The above command ran fine on my Mac. If you are using Windows, you might need to play around with the quote marks.)

Comment: Yes i was using AWS CLI to obtain it before but the reason I am trying with jq is to avoid multiple calls to AWS commands to obtain a set of results. My input remains the same which is volumes in my account. But there are quite a few filters I am trying to report separately and want to avoid calling AWS commands for each and every single report I am doing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Inian for helping me reach the answer

The final working jq filter for my query came to:

```
jq -r '.Volumes[] | select(any(.Tags[]; .Key == "Name")) | [.VolumeId,.Size,(.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name").Value)]|join(",")'
```

The output will be:

```
vol-123,20,abc
vol-456,22,def
```

Edited based on futher inputs from @Inian. Finally realised all of it can be piped across instead of multiple jq calls